# MySQL query using UPDATE, CASE and LEFT JOIN in one query

Tags: mysql, join, case

trying to get this combination of "UPDATE", "SET" with "CASES" AND LEFT JOIN to work, anyone able to help me?

```
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item`         
SET `csi`.`qty` = 
    CASE 
        WHEN `cpe`.`sku` = '03352828' THEN '1000'
        WHEN `cpe`.`sku` = '04975135' THEN '15150'  
    END
FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` csi
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` cpe 
ON `csi`.`product_id` = `cpe`.`entity_id`
```

But it throws syntax-error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` csi LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` cpe O' at line 7
```

Would help to reduce UPDATE query amount drastically.

Comment: Yep, you have to follow the syntax

Comment: The syntac for multi table update is UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition] - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `FROM` clause in the `UPDATE` query. In Update, you must "collect" the tables, and then use `SET`.

Do the following:

```
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS csi 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` cpe 
ON `csi`.`product_id` = `cpe`.`entity_id` 
SET `csi`.`qty` = 
    CASE 
        WHEN `cpe`.`sku` = '03352828' THEN '1000'
        WHEN `cpe`.`sku` = '04975135' THEN '15150'  
    END
```

[Syntax of Update clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]

value:
    {expr | DEFAULT}

assignment:
    col_name = value

assignment_list:
    assignment [, assignment] ...
```

Comment: Oke I found this example in another forum and the people there told this would work. But it was probably a forum for MSSQL not MySQL, maybe theres the big difference. I will try!

Comment: @Steini do try. If it helped you. Do consider marking it as accepted answer and optionally upvote. thanks :-)

Comment: @Steini you may also need to add a WHERE condition to avoid updating all of them accidentally